# Strange unexpected delay before mouseleave animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, delay

I'm currently trying to create a little animation when **hovering** a div using `.animate()` jQuery function.

If you take a look at the code snippet, you will see that there is a very strange delay between the time your mouse leave the div and the animation is launch.

It's definitely something with `.animate()` function because, there is a `console.log`  that is displayed when the mouse leave the div and without any strange delay.

Did I miss something or... Any ideas will be appreciate!

Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".square").hover(function() {
      var _this = this;
      $(_this).find(".square-hover").eq(0).animate({
        top: "0px",
      }, 750)
    })
    $(".square").mouseleave(function() {
      var _this = this;
      console.log("mouseleave triggered");
      $(_this).find(".square-hover").eq(0).animate({
        top: "-300px",
      }, 100)
    });
})
```

```css
.square {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-transition-property: background-color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 5px
}

.square-hover{
  position: absolute;
  top: -300px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(29, 233, 182, 0.85);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 square">
  <div class="square-hover"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Code should be posted **here**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're using `hover` and `mouseleave`. The `hover` event handler is actually separate `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` handlers - so you're actually attaching 1 `mouseenter` and 2 `mouseleave`. This is the cause of your issue.

If you change the code to pass two functions to `hover` (the first for `mouseenter`, second for `mouseleave`) your code works:

```
$(".square").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".square-hover").eq(0).stop(true).animate({
        top: "0px",
    }, 750)
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".square-hover").eq(0).stop(true).animate({
        top: "-300px",
    }, 100)
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4ywLdy05/8/)

Also note the use of `stop(true)` in the above to prevent successive events clogging up the animation queue.

Comment: Much better ! Thanks for the `strop(true)` tips.

Comment: Seems that if we leave and enter fast, the hovering div keep hovering.

Comment: Thats odd - that's what `stop(true)` should prevent

Comment: Yes but try, if the mouse leave the div before the animation is done, the hovering div will not be returned to her initial position (top : -300px)

Comment: Yeah you're right. There's logic issues with the shortened version. I'll remove it. The separate functions seem to work though